# How Could I add a Single Vert in Blender 3.0?

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects

I'm learning to use Blender. And I need to add a **Single Vert** using **Blender 3.0**. But I'm not finding the **option** in the **Floating menu** ( ***Shift + A*** ). How do I add **Single Vert** in **Blender 3.0**?

Grateful

Answer (score 8):

you can simply enable the built-in add-on : extra objects

[image]

[image]