# Extra Addon not apart of Version 3.2.2

Tags: mesh, add-on

I tried the following to add a single vert object in Blender 3.2.2:

[How Could I add a Single Vert in Blender 3.0?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/256771/how-could-i-add-a-single-vert-in-blender-3-0)

But I can't find it, was it removed from this version?

[image]

I can't for the life of me find Extra Addons. This is after using Revo for a fresh install due to some asset issues I was receiving. Just wanted to use the Single vert for making cables, but too busy stressing where to find the addon.

Comment: it's under *Community* tab. Not *Official* tab. Besides it's easy to add a single vertex. Just take a plane or cube and select all vertices with `A` then press `M` *> Merge at Center*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the *Add Mesh: Extra Objects* and *Add Curve: Extra Objects* are add-ons developed and maintained by the community. In your screenshot you are only searching within the category of official add-ons.

If you either click on the *Community* button or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>LMB</kbd> to have both *Official* and *Community* enabled, you should see the add-ons listed.